# throw ConverterNotFoundException using spring-cloud-consul for int property

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I got the following error message when starting a spring boot/cloud application which gets some properties from consul:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target demo.config.Config@5b4954b2 failed:

    Property: config.number
    Value: ${config.number:5}
    Reason: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'number'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [int]

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Here's my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@WebAppConfiguration
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the configuration property class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="config")
public class Config {   

    private int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

}
```

The application.yml file is:

```
server:
  port: 8100

spring:
 application:
    name: demo
```

And the bootstrap.yml file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
    config:
      enabled: true
      prefix: config 

config:
  number: ${config.number:5}
```

Finally the related part of maven pom.xml file:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    <cucumber.version>1.2.5</cucumber.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Any reason you think this has to do with spring-cloud-consul?

Comment: If without consul's key-value configuration, viz `config:number:5`, the app works fine for int type. And if the `number` is a string type, it also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is because `PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration` cannot locate property source from consul in some case. If `PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration` is properly initiated during the booting up, there's no such exception and the app works as expected.